# QT project get broken when make it subdir project

Tags: qt, testing

In QT Creator I decided to create autotest project where my tests will sit. My first step was to make my main project subdirs,but when I added the subdirs template , project won't build. It seems all classes which inherit from QObject are now "unknown type".
Here is my main project .pro file:

```
QT += quick
QT += core gui
QT += network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TEMPLATE = subdirs   
# the line above breaks project. Whithout it project compiles...
CONFIG += c++11 qml_debug declarative_debug console

win32 {
    LIBS += -lws2_32
}

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    applicationservice.cpp \
        blinkingtimer.cpp \
    shapes/genericshape.cpp \
        shapes/circle.cpp \
    shapes/textprint.cpp \
        shapes/tracksection.cpp \
        shapes/triangle.cpp \
        main.cpp \
    shapes/square.cpp \
    shapes/trainsignal.cpp \
    cliarguments.cpp \
    guimanager.cpp \
    desktopgeometry.cpp \
    tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

DISTFILES +=

HEADERS += \
    applicationservice.h \
    blinkingtimer.h \
    customtypes.h \
    shapes/genericshape.h \
    shapes/circle.h \
    shapes/textprint.h \
    shapes/tracksection.h \
    shapes/triangle.h \
    shapes/square.h \
    shapes/trainsignal.h \
    cliarguments.h \
    guimanager.h \
    desktopgeometry.h \
    tinyxml2/tinyxml2.h
```

Comment: What do your project files look like?

Answer (score 1):

A project cannot be both `subdirs` and `app` at the same time, which is what you're trying here.

The best way would be to move your main project into a subfolder (I've called it "App" here), same as your tests project ("Tests"). You then add an overarching subdirs project in the root folder:

**Folder structure:**

```
Rootdir/
|-- RootProject.pro
|-- App/
    |-- App.pro
    |-- <source files etc>
|-- Tests/
    |-- Tests.pro
    |-- <source files etc>
```

**RootProject.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
        App \
        Tests \
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to make App project static library?

Comment: Not necessarily, although splitting off some functionality into a separate library can help with testing. The main executable needs to be an app though, else it can't run.